# How to Serialize circular referenced object using JSON-B (Java API for JSON Binding)

Tags: java, json

I am using JSON-B for output object to json and there is a circular reference in the object (**please do not ask me to remove the circular reference**), sample code as follows

The Person class contains a list of Property
and the Property class reference back the person which form a circular reference.

In the first print the json can be output, however in the second print statement, stack overflow error due to touch the circular reference of the object, I do not want to use @JsonbTransient to ignore any of them, how can I solve this?

I am expecting the json output as

```
{"id":1,"name":"Jhon","propertyList":[{"person":1, "propertyName":"Palace"},{"person":1, "propertyName":"Apartment"}]}
```

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Person person = new Person(1, "Jhon");

        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

        //no error as no property is added
        System.out.println("jsonPerson without property: " + jsonb.toJson(person));

        Property p1 = new Property();
        p1.setPropertyName("Palace");
        p1.setPerson(person);

        Property p2 = new Property();
        p2.setPropertyName("Apartment");
        p2.setPerson(person);

        person.getPropertyList().add(p1);
        person.getPropertyList().add(p2);

        /**
         * stackoverflow here
         */
        System.out.println("jsonPerson with property: " + jsonb.toJson(person));
    }


    public static class Property {
        private Person person;
        private String propertyName;
        public Person getPerson() {
            return person;
        }
        public void setPerson(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
        public String getPropertyName() {
            return propertyName;
        }
        public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        private int id;

        public Person() {
            super();
        }

        public Person(int id, String name) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        private String name;

        private List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Property> getPropertyList() {
            return propertyList;
        }

        public void setPropertyList(List<Property> propertyList) {
            this.propertyList = propertyList;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In list why you need duplicate person? If you do not set person then this output will come... -> jsonPerson with property: `{"id":1,"name":"Jhon","propertyList":[{"propertyName":"Palace"},{"propertyName":"Apartment"}]}`

Comment: @Curiosity because it is a bidirectional relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I give up using JSON-B and instead use Jackson, use the annotation @JsonIdentityInfo here is my solution for information:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonTest {

    private static Person person = null;
    private static List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        person = new Person(1, "Jhon");
        propertyList.add(new Property(1, person, "Palace"));
        propertyList.add(new Property(2, person, "Apartment"));

        person.setPropertyList(propertyList);

        jacksonTest();
        //jsonbTest();
    }

    private static void jacksonTest()
    throws Exception
    {
        String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person);

        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }

    private static void jsonbTest()
    throws Exception
    {
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        /**
         * stackoverflow here
         */
        System.out.println("jsonPerson with property: " + jsonb.toJson(person));
    }

    public static class Property extends BaseEntity {
        private Person person;
        private String propertyName;

        public Property(int id, Person person, String propertyName) {
            super();
            setId(id);
            this.person = person;
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
        }

        public Person getPerson() {
            return person;
        }
        public void setPerson(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
        public String getPropertyName() {
            return propertyName;
        }
        public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }

    public static class Person extends BaseEntity {
        public Person() {
            super();
        }

        public Person(int id, String name) {
            super();
            setId(id);
            this.name = name;
        }

        private String name;

        private List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Property> getPropertyList() {
            return propertyList;
        }

        public void setPropertyList(List<Property> propertyList) {
            this.propertyList = propertyList;
        }

    }

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static abstract class BaseEntity {
        private int id;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
}
```

Jackson output:

```
result: {"id":1,"name":"Jhon","propertyList":[{"id":1,"person":1,"propertyName":"Palace"},{"id":2,"person":1,"propertyName":"Apartment"}]}
```